# How to hide elements, then reveal them when the DIV holding them gets clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, animation, jquery-animate

This is sort of hard to explain without you seeing it, so I recommend you look at the JSFiddle I posted. So basically when a certain div is clicked it expands down to reveal some inputs and buttons, but the problem I am having is that when the document loads the inputs and buttons are visible, when they should only appear when the DIV they are in expands to reveal them. I have already tried using .hide() in every way possible and cant figure out how to fix it.

**https://jsfiddle.net/v8u2q8re/**

```
<div>
  <div class='box' id='emailVer'>
    <h2 id='payText'>PAYMENT</h2>
  </div>

  <div class='box' id='accCust'>
    <h2 id='acText'>ACCOUNT CUSTOMIZATION</h2>
  </div>

  <div class='box' id='pay'>
    <h2 id='evText'>EMAIL VERIFICATION</h2>
    <div id='inputArea1' class='inputAreas'>
      <input id='email' class='evInput'>
      <input id='comf' class='evInput'>
      <button id='sndCde' class='evBut'>Send Code</button>
      <button id='comfBut' class='evBut'>Comfirm</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
var main = function(){
  $('.box').click(function() {
    var el = $(this); 
    if (!el.hasClass('selected')) {
      el.animate({
      "height": "300px"
    }, 200)
      el.addClass("selected");
      $('#inputAreas').show();
    } else {
      el.animate({
      "height": "85px"
    }, 200);
      $('#inputAreas').hide();
      el.removeClass("selected");
    }
  }
)}
$(document).ready(main);
```

I decided to leave the css out of the post as I do not think it matters for the problem I am having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
.inputAreas {
  display: none;
}
```

to your css to initially hide them. And then change

```
$('#inputAreas').show();
```

to

```
el.find('.inputAreas').show();
```

[Example](https://jsfiddle.net/gr78p763/)

Answer (score 1):

To fix this, add overflow to your CSS under .box:

`.box {
  ...
  overflow:hidden;
}`

Now anything "overflowing" your .box will be hidden. Though you may need to mess with the css some more for it to look the way you'd like. Good luck!

Update:
Here's a fiddle example: https://jsfiddle.net/doercreator/v8u2q8re/2/